# PHP Submitting data to URL over HTTPS

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that's receiving GET data and posting it to another URL using stream_get_contents.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://submitting-domain.com");
$url = https://example.url
$getData = "Example data";
$getDataLength = strlen($getData);
$opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"POST",
      'header'=>"Content-type: text/xml\r\n" .
                "Content-Length: ".$getDataLength."\r\n",
                "content"=>$getData
        )
    );

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
return $response;
```

When the URL is http://example.url it all works fine but when I change it to https://example.url it fails to connect. I couldn't find much documentation on how to create a stream with a secure connection but one suggestion was to ensure that the open_ssl extension was installed.

Unfortunately it's proving difficult to get this done (it's on a client's server) but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or could see if I was doing something wrong?

I've tried setting the initial opts array http key to https but nothing changed.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

**Edit: Enabling the open_ssl extension in PHP solved the error**

Comment: Well do you have the open_ssl module installed or not? You can hardly expect something that relies on that module being available to work if it’s not …

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you try using the CURL functions?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php